# I have trouble drawing on some pages of the photo gallery

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a photo gallery and want to enable mouse or touch drawing for only some pages.

In the Adobe Animate program I put a page code in the gallery, but when I get to the page whose frame contains the drawing code, the drawing becomes effective on that page and all pages and I cannot stop the mouse from drawing in the rest of the gallery pages.

How do I customize the code for drawing only on specific pages?

Link to the file I'm working on : [the FLA file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12MFTKvWQE_nncf5kzYouCV620pxKCkJh).

The pages to be assigned to the drawing are 10 and 14.

Comment: I'm not downloading your file because that shouldn't be needed. Try to show the problematic part of your code here by using the [**edit** button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61977210/edit). As a possible solution, did you try an `IF` statement to only draw if frame number is 10 or 14? `if ( (currentFrame == 10) || (currentFrame == 14) )  { /* enable drawing code here */  }`

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I tried the method that you explained to me, the problem was solved, and the code is working properly

Comment: I have another question that I could not ask in the question window
I have a type text box (input text) When I write the numbers inside it appears in English like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ... but I want it to appear in Arabic (Eastern) like ۰,۱,۲,۳,٤,٥,٦,۷,۸,۹ ... However, I'm a beginner in learning Action Script 3, and I can't create custom code for that. Please write an integrated code** to solve the problem. With all respect and appreciation

Comment: For Arabic you need to use a font called **Arial Unicode**. If you need it you can [download here](https://github.com/kaienfr/Font/raw/master/font/ARIALUNI.TTF) (right-click and save) . In Fash, select your textbox and give it that font. Now you can have Arabic characters in your text box.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your instructions were important and enabled me to solve the problem